# Reload div content outside an iframe by clicking inside an iframe div, with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an mainpage, we will call it "main.php". At this page exists an iframe, we will call it "frameX".

**1. Example html of "main.php"**

```
<html>
<div class="result">20</div>
<div class="result">25</div>
<div class="result">154</div>
<iframe id="X"></iframe>
</html>
```

**2. Example html of "frameX":**

```
<div class="button"></div>
```

The content of the "frameX" and the "main.php" are from the same URL (like: www.example.com)

**Now the question:**
How can I reload all "result" divs (outside the iframe) by clicking at the "button" div (inside the iframe)?

**I have tried** the jQuery "load" function:

```
$( '.button' ).click(function() {
    $(".result").load("https://www.example.com/main.php" + ".result");
});
```

... but this works for me only at the same page. Has anybody a simple solution? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to indicate the context where jQuery will select the elements.

```
$( '.button' ).click(function() {
    $(".result", window.parent.document).load("https://www.example.com/main.php" + ".result");
});
```

Comment: Thx 4 support - thats something I was looking for - I will try it!

Comment: So, sry for the late reply, now it works - thx! Btw., dont forget the quotation marks around the URL ;) ... I couldn't edit your answer, dont know why.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no onClick event for an `iframe`, but you can hook to the actual document inside the iframe.

```
document.getElementById("iframe-id").contentWindow.document.body.onclick = 
function() {
  $(".result").load(https://www.example.com/main.php + ".result");
}
```

Note: this will only work if the iframe is rendering a page within the same domain.